# Sharing proto files in docker?

Tags: docker-compose, protocol-buffers, grpc, project-layout

I was wondering how people tend to share proto files between clients and servers in docker composites? I'm testing out gRPC for fun and created a project with the following layout:

```
docker-compose.yml
front/Dockerfile
      ...
back/Dockerfile
     proto/
     ...
```

Here `front` is the gRPC client to the `back` server. Now `back/proto` contains the protobuf files that I need for generating the client stub. The problem here is that this is outside the context for `front`. Anyone who uses these have any best practices to share for handling this?

Answer (score 0):

I have two options for you:

## Docker Multistage Build

You could use a [docker multi-stage build](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/).  Generate the back docker container first, then use multi-stage build to pull the `.proto` files from the `back` container to the `front` container.

The `front` container Dockerfile could look something like:

```
FROM back AS builder

FROM alpine:latest  
COPY --from=builder proto/ proto/
...other commands...
```

## Extended Build Context

Another option would be to issue the `docker build` command from the directory above:

```
docker build -f back/Dockerfile .
docker build -f front/Dockerfile .
```

This would extend the build context to include both `front` and `back` directories.  That way you could just reference `back/proto/` in your `front` Dockerfile.

Comment: Could someone elaborate on the answer for the complete newbies?